# ionic application run error : Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

i am developing **Hybrid app** using `ionic`. i want to use `barcode scanner` within it.
i am installing `barcode scanner plugin` using https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/

plugin install successfully but after that when i try to deploye my app on android devices using command

> ionic run android

I'm getting this following error

[image: Error]

Here is version list :

```
ionic -v  :  2.1.0

cordova -v :  6.4.0

npm -v :  2.15.9

node -v : 4.6.0
```

I dont know , why my project does not run in device, please help me.

Sorry for my english.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/535

Comment: Thanks for the link of the barcodescanner without dependency on cordova-plugin-compat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all plugins then have dependencies on `cordova-plugin-compat`, listed here: https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/10/plugins-release.html

Remove plugin itself and re-install platform.

`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.4.0`

This should help.

Comment: but in command **cordova platform add android@6.4.0** i am getting this error `Error: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

In  platforms -> android ->project.properties file **change**

**from**

cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+

**to**

cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0